# How can we save and retrieve datetime type multiple values in single column of sql server and its best practice

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I have dates which are datetime type in c#,like 

2014-01-31 04:08:00.000,
2014-02-11 02:51:00.000,
2014-02-25 13:13:00.000 etc,?
So I need to save it on single column of type varchar(500) in sql server.Also need to extract from it also best practices.

Comment: Saving dates as `varchar` and you asking for 'best' practice?

Comment: So please suggest, how to save multiple values in single column on sql server.

Comment: Saving dates in varchar itself is not a good idea and saving multiple dates in single field is really a bad idea.

Comment: Do not do it...

Comment: Save them in DATETIME format.

Comment: I think you want to save in single row instead of single column but you can save data in multiple rows and you can easily retrieve that in single row if needed. Datatype should be DATETIME

Comment: **Given the premise which many have already voiced their suggestions on, it's important to know what you have tried?**

Comment: Surely, saving comma-separated values is well-known technique, though, as others have mentioned, you should refrain from saving multiple dates as varchar in a single column. If possible, you should rather look into changing the way you are storing the data.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you know that you're not supposed to store DateTime as varchar on your database, but if yours project's requirement is to store multiple datetimes on a single column, I would probably construct a Json with those dates and store the json string in the database. So you could easily serialize it back in your code with Newtonsoft Json .NET.